# Logging handleError() not intercepting exception

Tags: python, python-logging

I created a custom Python logging handler, where I overrode the handleError() method.  In order to test it, I deleted the directory containing the log file to force a logging error.  I was expecting this to trigger a call to handleError() the next time I tried to log something with the logger.  However, this did not happen.  The exception was passed directly through to my method doing the logging.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```
import logging
import os
import shutil

from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler
from pathlib import Path

class MySpecialWatchedFileHandler(WatchedFileHandler):
    def handleError(self, record):
        print("******************** HANDLING AN ERROR!!!! *********************")
        super().handleError(record)

print("************** Start ************")
test_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
test_logger.handlers = []
log_directory = "/tmp/test_logdir"
Path(log_directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
handler = MySpecialWatchedFileHandler(os.path.join(log_directory, "test_logfile.log"), delay=False)
test_logger.addHandler(handler)
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Force a failure by deleting the logging directory, so that it does not auto-recover.
shutil.rmtree(log_directory, ignore_errors=False)

test_logger.info("This is a test")
print("************** End ************")
```

**Resulting output:**

```
/home/joe/percipient/mirage-backend-django/venv/bin/python /home/joe/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py
************** Start ************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 25, in <module>
    test_logger.info("This is a test")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 481, in emit
    self.reopenIfNeeded()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 471, in reopenIfNeeded
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test_logdir/test_logfile.log'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that `******************** HANDLING AN ERROR!!!! *********************` is never printed.

Why is my handler not catching that exception?

Not sure if it matters, but I've tried it with `logging.raiseExceptions` set to both `True` and `False`, and also setting delay to both `True` and `False` in the handler, and the behavior is the same either way on both options.

Comment: Have you tried using [try and except?](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Comment: @llamaking136 Yes, I have, and that of course catches the exception, but I'm worried that not all logging errors will necessarily manifest themselves as exceptions, and I want to test the actual official error handling mechanism.

Comment: Did you set the `delay` parameter on the file handler? I can't reproduce your error. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @blues Thanks.  I have tried `delay` set to both `True` and `False`, and it doesn't make a difference.  I have updated my question to a minimal reproducible example, along with the resulting output.  I ran this in a scratch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I finally solved it.  In my custom handler, I overrode the emit() method, with my own try/except around the call the super class's emit() method, so that it now catches the exception while opening the log fine and routes it to my handleError() method.

```
class MySpecialWatchedFileHandler(WatchedFileHandler):
    def handleError(self, record):
        print("****** HANDLING AN ERROR!!!! *****")
        #
        # Do what I need to do to handle the error here
        #

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            super().emit(record)
        except Exception:
            record.exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            self.handleError(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "bug" in python. Basically the `reopenIfNeeded()` method on the WatchedFileHandler is not wrapped into the try/except block that catches all other logging errors. There is two possible changes to make this work depending on what the goal is:

1.) only delete the log file, and not the directory that contains it. the WatchedFileHandler will be able to detect this and recover by recreating the file

2.) Use a regular `FileHandler` instead of the WatchedFileHandler. no attempt to recreate the missing file will be made, and the error will be handled by `handleError` as expected

Comment: Thanks @blues. I was just looking at the source code and came to the same conclusion.  Regarding your suggestions:
1) I tried this.  It just recreates the file and doesn't trigger the error handler.  I need to trigger the error handler because I'm trying to test my custom error handler.
2) For our implementation, we need WatchedFileHandler.

Do you know of any other ways to trigger a logging error that won't cause an exception in reopenIfNeeded(), but WILL trigger one inside the try/except block?

Comment: 1.) is the purpose of WatchedFileHandler. if you need an error for testing purposes you should mock emit. No reason to mess around like this

Comment: What do you mean by "is the purpose of WatchedFileHandler"?

Comment: well, the purpose of the WatchedFileHandler is to recreate the log file if it gets deleted instead of throwing an error

Comment: Yes, that's what it does if you delete the log file, and that's fine.  The issue is if you delete the DIRECTORY containing the log file.  That throws an error no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the exception via `sys.exc_info` like so:

```
import sys
import logging


def handleLoggingError(record):
    print(f"exc_info: {sys.exc_info()}")


hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
hdlr.handleError = handleLoggingError
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```